# Need some help understanding Application.Transpose()

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Could someone explain what is happening here? Preferably line for line. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around what is happening with this bit.

```
                a = Application.Transpose(a)
            For i = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                If UCase(a(1, i)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Or _
                UCase(a(2, i)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Then
                    n = n + 1
                    For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
                        a(ii, n) = a(ii, i)
                    Next
                End If
            Next
```

I am also experiencing a "type mismatch" error for the above. See full Sub below.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Search_Change()
Select Case True
    Case OptionButton_User_Name.Value
        Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, n As Long, temp As String
        If Len(Me.TextBox_Search.Value) Then
            temp = UCase(Me.TextBox_Search.Value)
            With Sheets("ToolData")
                a = Union(.Range("B:B"), .Range("F:F"), .Range("G:G")).Value
            End With
            a = Application.Transpose(a)
            For i = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                If UCase(a(1, i)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Or _
                UCase(a(2, i)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Then
                    n = n + 1
                    For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
                        a(ii, n) = a(ii, i)
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            If n > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve a(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To n)
                Me.ListBox_History.Column = a
            End If
        Else
            With Sheets("ToolData")
                Me.ListBox_History.List = Union(.Range("B:B"), .Range("F:F"), .Range("G:G")).Value
            End With
        End If

    Case Else
End Select
```

Comment: Where did you find this piece of *code* ? And what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Its for searching a WorkSheet for values that are typed into a TextBox(whether whole or partial) and populating a ListBox with found values and there Rows.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff196261.aspx

Comment: `Union(.Range("B:B"), .Range("F:F"), .Range("G:G")).Value` is only going to return the `Value` property of the first area, so is effectively `.Range("B:B").Value`.  Once that is returned (as a 1048576 x 1 array), the `Transpose` will switch the rows and columns, but is limited to 65536 values so you will end up with a 1 x 65536 array.

Comment: @YowE3K So a work around  would be to 1. find values in column B and 2. list them in Column 0 of a ListBox. 3. Then get the Row of every value in ListBox column 0 and 4. populate ListBox column 1, 2 with the worksheet column G and F. Seems a bit unnecessary and rigged but I don't know how to do it any other way.

Comment: @YowE3K Never mind found a much easier work around using `.RemoveItem` Just delete the columns I don't need. Instead of trying to populate with ones I do want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the `True` portion of your `If` statement as

```
temp = UCase(Me.TextBox_Search.Value)
Dim rngValues As Variant
With Sheets("ToolData")
    rngValues = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 6).Value
End With
For i = 1 To UBound(rngValues, 1)
    'Check columns B & F for matching values
    If UCase(rngValues(i, 1)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Or _
       UCase(rngValues(i, 5)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Then
        'Store columns B, F & G for displaying in the ListBox
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve a(1 To 3, 1 To n)
        a(1, n) = rngValues(i, 1)
        a(2, n) = rngValues(i, 5)
        a(3, n) = rngValues(i, 6)
    End If
Next
'If anything found, replace the ListBox contents.  Otherwise leave it as it was.
If n > 0 Then
    Me.ListBox_History.Column = a
End If
```

thus getting rid of the code which is reading into memory all 1048576 rows of your sheet, and the need of the `Transpose` (which won't work on large volumes of data).

You will also need to change the `False` leg of your `If`, perhaps in a similar fashion.

Comment: I get an "Expected Array" Error from this bit `For i = 1 To UBound(rngValues, 1)` When I add option explicit I get a different error what would I need to defined `temp` by?

Comment: @WilliamSmith - (a) Sorry - I started off intending to use a `Range`, then decided to just put the `Value` straight into the array, and forgot to change the `Dim` statement to be `Dim rngValues As Variant`.  Will edit the answer. (b) `temp` is still your original variable and is a `String`

Comment: okay that working fine now. Just need to declare `a` as what? Error out for this part `ReDim Preserve a(1 To 3, 1 To n)` "Variable not defined"

Comment: @WilliamSmith Sorry - another oversight on my part - your current declaration of `a` (`Dim a`) will need to be changed to `Dim a()`.

Comment: Awesome it seems to be working properly. If I wanted to search only B column and display B,C,F,G,J,K. How would that look?

Comment: @WilliamSmith (a) Change the bit where you are checking columns B & F so that you only check column B (b) Use a `Resize(, 10)` to read 10 columns into `rngSize` instead of 6 (c) Change the bit where you are storing results to `ReDim` the array to be `1 To 6` instead of `1 To 3` (d) Change the bit where you are storing results to store the values from the extra columns into `a(4, n)` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for making this easy to follow. I learned quite a bit more about arrays from your answers and simple google searches from the bits of your answer I didn't understand.

Comment: @WilliamSmith - Google is our friend!!  Repeat that at least 5 times daily.  :D

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `.Value` on a multi-area range: you will only get values from the first column (B).

Comment: So a work around would be to List column B values then find the rows and populate the rest of the list box with column F and G? No other way?